# VB script to copy folder template (& permissions), into multiple user selected folders

Tags: vbscript, subdirectory, robocopy

Long time searcher, 1st time poster.

I have put together a vb script my users can run from explorer that will allow them to create and name a new folder and then robocopy a template structure into the new folder.  I used robocopy so the intricate folder permissions would copy with the template, which is the main motivation behind the script.

I am by no means an expert with vb. So happy to here any advise on this Script, but this script works nicely for the users.....so far anyway!!!

```
      SetobjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
      Call Entercompanyname
      Function Entercompanyname
      companyname = InputBox("Please enter the new company name" & vbLf & "(or select cancel to  it)", _
      "Create New Company Folder")
     If IsEmpty(companyname) Then 
     Cancel = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit ?", 68, "Exit Application?") 
     If Cancel = vbYes Then 
         WScript.Quit 
     ElseIf Cancel = vbNo Then 
         Call Entercompanyname 
     End If 
 ElseIf Len(companyname) = 0 Then 
     MsgBox "You clicked OK but did not enter a new company name", 64, "Error: No Company Name entered" 
     Call Entercompanyname 
 End If

     objSource = "\\serverxx\Data\Accounts\Accounting\company_template"
     objDestination = ("\\serverxx\Data\Accounts\Accounting\" & companyname)

     objCommand = "RoboCopy.Exe " & Chr(34) & objSource & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & objDestination & Chr(34) & "  /sec /e /r:1 /w:2"
      objShell.Run(objCommand)
```

Now the department head has come back to me and asked for a new script to be able to create new year folder in each of the company names. We will have a template for the new year, but they want to be able to choose which companies the new year folder gets created.

Has anyone got any advise.

Thanks in advance!!

I have been asked for an example.  I have found this, which is sort of what I am chasing, but this only lets the user select one company.  So the process would need to be repeated, which I know will cause dramas

```
    WScript.Echo BrowseFolder( "\\serverxx\Data\Accounts\Accounting", True )

Function BrowseFolder( myStartLocation, blnSimpleDialog )

Const MY_COMPUTER   = &H11&
Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0 ' Must ALWAYS be 0

Dim numOptions, objFolder, objFolderItem
Dim objPath, objShell, strPath, strPrompt

strPrompt = "Select a folder:"
If blnSimpleDialog = True Then
numOptions = 0      ' Simple dialog
Else
    numOptions = &H10&  
End If


Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

   If UCase( myStartLocation ) = "MY COMPUTER" Then
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace( MY_COMPUTER )
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    strPath = objFolderItem.Path
Else
    strPath = myStartLocation
End If

Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( WINDOW_HANDLE, strPrompt, _
                                      numOptions, strPath )

If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    BrowseFolder = ""
    Exit Function
End If


Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
objPath = objFolderItem.Path

End Function
```

Comment: How about an example to illustrate what you want? And how exactly do they want to choose, based on the entered company?

Comment: hi @groverboy.  I have edited my original post with something that I have found, but it only lets you choose 1 folder at a time

Comment: Essentially it will be a process for a new financial yr. The way I see it working is inputbox for the user to enter the new yr, and then they are able to select the existing companies that require a folder for the new year. inputbox variable & chosen companies are combined to create destination for robocopy.

Comment: You could have added Excel and use it's built-in folder dialogue boxes for multiple folder selection in one prompt. Imagine if 90% of companies needs to do this, you could save tens of name typing in one popup. See [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226(v=office.14).aspx)